# Distribute new mailbox among various databases

Tags: powershell, scripting, exchange-server

I am creating a PowerShell script to create several shared mailboxes from Excel spreadsheet.
I would like to have the new mailboxes distributed amongst our various databases, based on the `AvailableNewMailboxSpace` attribute.
I have a variable `$db= @("list of databases")`. What script/function do I use to assign new mailbox to the database with most space at that moment of time?

Comment: Hey @Joel Bwana - could you please review my answer and let me know if that helped and if yes, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort your databases by the property you mentioned:

```
$sortedDatabases = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Sort-Object AvailableNewMailboxSpace -Descending
```

This will give you the sorted list. If you only want to see the one with most space available use:

```
$selectedDatabase = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | Sort-Object AvailableNewMailboxSpace -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

All you have to do is to provide the identity of selected database to `New-Mailbox`. Keeping in mind that properties can be accessed by using `$selectedDatabase.PropertyName` you should already have all the information you need.